# Need call details in iOS 10 using CallKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, callkit

In iOS 10 a new framework come CallKit, My target is:
In my application when a incoming call come, I want some information like:
1. Call State
2. Call duration
3. Phone Number
4. User Name

I found that in CoreTelephony framework this is not possible but is this possible in CallKit framework.
I also want CallKit framework example in Objective C, how to use this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CallKit also, you are not able to get the Call History of User, as it will effect the Privacy of User and it is not allowed.

For more info check [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/45891)

Comment: so how this application use call history https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/callog/id327883585?mt=8

Comment: Check the apps first screenshot, they give option to make the call within there application, Also have you used it in your phone ?

Comment: Check this - http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple49/v4/37/e5/70/37e570bd-3e65-8184-d3b2-a223565f404b/screen696x696.jpeg

Comment: means this app fetch our phone book..but this is not give information about incoming and missed calls and call history.

Comment: Just check the app first, they clearly mentioned that through there app they are managing there history, not from the default call history

Comment: Thank You...I have not read the full description of this application...

Comment: I hope you will connect with me in future.